# Basic Instructions for Connecting local Neo4j server to Visual Studios Project

Tags: visual-studio, neo4j, neo4jclient

Can someone please let me know what is the most basic way to take my local neo4j server and add it into my Visual Studios Project? Using c# if possible.

I have seen people use this:

```
GraphClient _client = new GraphClient
```

but i wasn't which assemblies they are using or how they are getting this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a the [Neo4jClient package](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient). This is .NET client for Neo4j. Installation instructions are [here](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki):

> Neo4jClient ships exclusively as a NuGet package.
>   To install it, run Install-Package Neo4jClient in the NuGet Package Manager Console.

Once installed, to create a connection to a Neo4j instance running locally:

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

More info available in the [docs](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki).